# Does LinqToSql support text file connections?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, connection-string, text-files

I am having trouble getting a connection string initialized to a text file when using LinqToSQL.

I am trying to create a DataContext using the following connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\dat\;Extended Properties=text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited
```

I keep getting errors that the 'Keyword Provider is not supported.'  I've also tried 'providerName' and received the same error.

I wonder if this is masking an inability to support using Text files as connections.  Can LinqToSql do what I want it to do?  If so, can someone provide a working example of the string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ah well .. that explains it !  Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ To SQL supports only SQL Server as its target.

If you're looking for something like LINQ To Text File, try this article: [LINQ To Text Files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2006/08/31/734383.aspx) by Eric White. He's got sample code that you can modify for the layout of your text file.

Answer (score 1):

LinqToSql only supports Microsoft SQL Server, and I think also the compact edition, but that's it.

The Entity Framework supports other database engines, but I'm not sure about text files, but LinqToSql won't do it.